# DIV inside a TD with rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

My question might be silly, but I need to ask.

Is it possible to place a `<div>` inside a `<td>` which `<span>` several rows without setting `<td>`'s `rowspan` atTribute? I know `<div>` does not have a `rowspan` attribute.

Like:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="item row-span-4">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    <tr>
</tbody>
```

Code appareance:

[image: Code appearence]

Comment: why not give `td` rowspan=4 and fill it with `div` ?

Comment: There will be too much manipulation within the table. I will add, move, delete so many DIVs and it will bring too much manipulation over table. I am thinking of a safer and a shorter approach. Doing, undoing each and every table cells with so many actions will increase complexity.

Comment: you want the div to overlap the 3 next TD?

Comment: CSS grid instead of a table may be an option: https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

Comment: Yes, but in a vertical manner.

Comment: use Bootstrap Grid System and remove Table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we consider the fact that you will have the **same height** for your cells then you can do this relying on the height property:

```css
td {
  border: 1px #ddd solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position:relative;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.item {
  background:red;
}
[class*="row-span"] {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
.row-span-4 {
  height:calc(400% + 3*1px);
}
.row-span-3 {
  height:calc(300% + 2*1px);
}
.row-span-2 {
  height:calc(200% + 1*1px);
}
.row-span-1 {
  height:calc(100% + 0*1px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <div class="item row-span-4"></div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="item row-span-3"></div></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="item row-span-1"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: That looks exactly what I need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can't do that using only html but you can do it by using JavaScript

here an example using JQuery :

```js
$("div.row-span").each(function(){
  var rowSpan = $(this).data("rowspan")
  $(this).parents("td").attr("rowspan",rowSpan)
})
```

```css
td {border:1px #ddd solid;text-align:center;padding:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1-1</td>
        <td>
          <div class="item row-span" data-rowspan="2">Div</div>
        </td>
        <td>1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2-1</td>
        <td>2-2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

**Another Solution :** Here another Solution That overlaying the `td` with absolute layer of div which takes its height dynamically from `data-rowspan` attribute

```js
$("div.row-span").each(function(){
  var rowSpan = $(this).data("rowspan")
  //$(this).parents("td").attr("rowspan",rowSpan)
  var divHeight = $(this).parents("td").innerHeight()*rowSpan;
  $(this).height(divHeight)
  
})
```

```css
td {border:1px #ddd solid;text-align:center;position:relative}
div.row-span {background-color:#ff0000;position:absolute;top:0;z-index:2}
table {border-spacing: 0;border-collapse: collapse;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>1-1</td>
          <td>1-2</td>
          <td>2-3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>2-1</td>
          <td>
            <div class="item row-span" data-rowspan="2">2-2</div>
          </td>
          <td>2-3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>3-1</td>
          <td>3-2</td>
          <td>3-3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>4-1</td>
          <td>4-2</td>
          <td>4-3</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: You are still manipulating <td> but over <div> this time. Not I have expected but makes quite sense. I will try this approach. Thank you.

Comment: @user3021830 I don't see why doing such thing. Adding an attribute to one element to later put it (using jQuery!) inside another element. It doesn't make a lot of sense. Simply add the attribute on the td and you will have the same result with a more logical code

Comment: @TemaniAfif , i think he needs to overlaying the current `td` with rowspan layer data with control on div attribute without affect on the `td` itself . So @user3021830 i added another solution maybe help you with dynamic rowspan attribute .